# How to programatically create a simple HTML page using the permalink of another Wordpress post?

Tags: php, jquery, html, facebook, wordpress

I want a create a simple HTML page (not Wordpress Page) programmatically by using the permalink structure of another already existing post.

E.g. Already existing post is `www.example.com/this-is-example-post`

I want to create 3 more pages viz.

```
www.example.com/this-is-example-post/index1
www.example.com/this-is-example-postindex2
www.example.com/this-is-example-post/index3
```

These URLs need not be real pages. I just need three different pages to store different Facebook meta. I'm building a plugin. Please guide.
How can I achieve it?

Am I thinking twisted? I'm going crazy thinking about it. :( Please help.

**-------------EDIT---------------**

After working on suggestions from Rahil, here's where I'm now

```
<?php 
add_action( 'init', 'xx_add_endpoint' );

function xx_add_endpoint()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'index', EP_PERMALINK );
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'xx_render_endpoint' );

function xx_render_endpoint()
{
    if ( ! is_singular() or ! get_query_var( 'index' ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    // Do somthing here
    exit;
}


add_filter( 'request', 'xx_set_endpoint_var' );

function xx_set_endpoint_var( $vars )
{
    isset( $vars['index'] ) and $vars['index'] = true;
    return $vars;
}

?>
```

But I'm trying to understand how I can pass variables to this request e.g. `www.example.com/this-is-example-post/index/20/1`, `www.example.com/this-is-example-post/index/20/2`, `www.example.com/this-is-example-post/index/20/3` and so on.

p.s. I intend to pass two values viz. `/index/a/b` where `a`,`b` are the two values to be sent and handled under `xx_render_endpoint` function.

Please guide.

Comment: Try look at [add_rewrite_endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)

Comment: Hi @RahilWazir, can you kindly elaborate more. How can rewrite endpoint help me in this regard? I'm a bit new to WP, kindly guide.

Comment: Hi @RahilWazir, I went through the doc of Add Rewrite Endpoint, but it only gives me the option to say make `www.example.com/this-is-example-post/index` where `index` is the is the `$name` parameter. How will i get more than one endpoint?

Comment: Yes you can do append multiple endpoints with the same post/page.

Comment: What about I create a single endpoint named "index" and when the user goes to `www.example.com/sample-post/index/2`, in the logic I can prefill the Facebook meta for the display `www.example.com/sample-post/index/2` is going to render? Is that possible? I'll need that value of '2' to know what to send to FB meta.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You want me to show you a sample? It is better you should first attempt and than come back if you need help.

Comment: Hey @RahilWazir, thanks for guiding me till here. I've edited the question to add my progress till now. But I'm still stuck at how to pass variables, can you guide me please. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55252/discussion-between-littlelebowski-and-rahil-wazir).

Comment: Remember the endpoint expects the endpoint should be like key value pairs. E.g: `/index` is key and `2` is the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's how you can do it. Remove the `template_redirect` filter, you don't have use this. Instead use `template_include` filter ([which is the proper way to load alternate template](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/))

See my code comments for explanation.

```
add_action( 'template_include', 'xx_render_endpoint');

function xx_render_endpoint($default_template)
{
    global $wp_query;

    // If this isn't singular page or index is not the endpoint
    // return default template

    if ( ! is_singular() || !isset($wp_query->query_vars['index']) )
    {
        return $default_template;
    }

    // our custom template selection variable which default to null
    // or you can set a template for just "index" key
    // Like: plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/your-template-index.php';

    $template_selection = null;

    // Why we're exploding index value string into array? As i said in comments
    // key => value (index => 1/2). So if you have a url like
    // this "post-name/index/1/2", then "1/2" is the value of key "index"
    // so we have to separate both values in your case.

    $indexes = explode('/', get_query_var('index'));

    // Assuming the values "1/2" isset in the url hold the absolute path
    // to the template on our $template_selection variable
    // Same for the second elseif block instead its just select value "1"

    if (isset($indexes[0], $indexes[1])) {
        $template_selection = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/your-template-1-2.php';
    } else if (isset($indexes[0])) {
        $template_selection = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/your-template-1.php';
    }

    // If our $template_selection variable is not null assign the value
    // to $default_template which is the required parameter of template_include filter

    if (isset($template_selection)) {
        $default_template = $template_selection;
    }

    // Fallback for default template and our template selection
    return $default_template;
}
```

**Note:** You need to flush the permalinks plus make sure your permalink structure must be pretty otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Hi @Rahil, this looks great & thank you so much for the detailed comments. You rock, man! In my case I want run a query using the values indexes[0] and indexes[1]. The query will return a set of values with which I need to generate a HTML page. So do I have to make a `my-template.php` file where I can append/replace these values? Am I heading towards the right direction?

Comment: Yes go create a custom template where you can generate the html based on the values.

Comment: Great, and one last quick question: where should I add the endpoint code? Can ti go under functions.php in my child theme?

Comment: If you are developing a plugin you should keep there. Otherwise yes place it on current active theme `functions.php`